# datatable to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a datatable with three columns

```
Id name value value1
```

I want to create a string from this datatable so that

1. each row in datatable will create two rows
2. name will become one row
3. value 1 will become another row
4. If name and value1 are similar then include value 1 only otherwise include both name and value1 (this is done)
5. If name of one row is similar to name in any other row, then add following text infront of both duplicate rows in string

*Id is similar to Id*

This is what I have written so far:

```
Public Function GetGazetteer(dataTable As DataTable) As String
            Dim processedData = New List(Of String)
            Dim rowData = String.Empty
            Dim results = New StringBuilder()

            For Each row As DataRow In dataTable.Rows
                processedData.Add(row(1))
                If row(3) <> row(1) Then
                    processedData.Add(row(3))
                End If
            Next

            For Each row As String In processedData
                rowData = row

                If rowData.Trim <> String.Empty Then
                    If (processedData.Where(Function(d) d = rowData).Count = 1) Then
                        results.Append(rowData)
                        results.Append("<br />")
                    Else
                        results.Append(rowData)
                        results.Append("*")
                        results.Append("<br />")
                    End If
                End If

            Next

            Return results.ToString
        End Function
```

Currently, `*` is added ( please suggest how to add above text.)

Here is a sample

```
id   name           value  value1
1    this is string 1       abc    This is sample
2    this is string 2       abc    this is string 2
3    this is string 3       abc    this is string 4
4    this is string 3       abc    asasaasd
```

Here is desired output

```
this is string 1
This is sample
this is string 2
*3 is duplicate of 4* this is string 3
this is string 4
*4 is duplicate of 3* this is string 3
asasaasd
```

Comment: Give some table values and resultant strings output sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited based on output given on question**

Here is a solution using C# (hope you can convert this to VB.NET). I have used a struct to hold id, value, col information.

The struct is

```
    public struct Container
    {
       public int Id;
       public int Col;
       public string Value;
    }
```

The method is

```
        public string GetGazetteer(DataTable dtInput)
        {
            string result = null;
            List<Container> containers = new List<Container>();
            List<Container> finalContainers = new List<Container>();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (DataRow row in dtInput.Rows)
            {
                Container container;
                container = new Container() { Id = int.Parse(row[0].ToString()), Value = row[1].ToString(), Col = 1 };
                containers.Add(container);
                if (row[1] != row[3])
                {
                    container = new Container() { Id = int.Parse(row[0].ToString()), Value = row[3].ToString(), Col = 2 };
                    containers.Add(container);
                }
            }

            containers = containers.OrderBy(c => c.Value).ThenBy(c => c.Id).ToList();

            if (containers.Count > 0)
            {
                string initialVal = containers[0].Value;
                finalContainers.Add(containers[0]);
                for (int i = 1; i < containers.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (containers[i].Value == initialVal)
                    {
                        finalContainers.Remove(containers[i]);
                        finalContainers.Remove(containers[i - 1]);
                        finalContainers.Add(new Container() { Id = containers[i - 1].Id, Value = "*" + containers[i - 1].Id + " is duplicate of " + containers[i].Id + "* " + containers[i - 1].Value });
                        finalContainers.Add(new Container() { Id = containers[i].Id, Value = "*" + containers[i].Id + " is duplicate of " + containers[i - 1].Id + "* " + containers[i].Value });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        finalContainers.Add(containers[i]);
                    }

                    initialVal = containers[i].Value;
                }

                finalContainers = finalContainers.OrderBy(c => c.Id).ThenBy(c => c.Col).ToList();

                foreach (Container container in finalContainers)
                {
                    sb.Append(container.Value + "</br>");
                }

                result = sb.ToString();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

This is the sample datatable I used for testing

```
            DataTable dtInput = new DataTable();
            dtInput.Columns.Add("id");
            dtInput.Columns.Add("name");
            dtInput.Columns.Add("value");
            dtInput.Columns.Add("value1");

            DataRow drInput1 = dtInput.NewRow();
            drInput1[0] = "1";
            drInput1[1] = "this is string 1";
            drInput1[2] = "abc";
            drInput1[3] = "This is sample";
            dtInput.Rows.Add(drInput1);

            DataRow drInput2 = dtInput.NewRow();
            drInput2[0] = "2";
            drInput2[1] = "this is string 2";
            drInput2[2] = "abc";
            drInput2[3] = "this is string 2";
            dtInput.Rows.Add(drInput2);

            DataRow drInput3 = dtInput.NewRow();
            drInput3[0] = "3";
            drInput3[1] = "this is string 3";
            drInput3[2] = "abc";
            drInput3[3] = "this is string 4";
            dtInput.Rows.Add(drInput3);

            DataRow drInput4 = dtInput.NewRow();
            drInput4[0] = "4";
            drInput4[1] = "this is string 3";
            drInput4[2] = "abc";
            drInput4[3] = "asasaasd";
            dtInput.Rows.Add(drInput4);
```

output will be

```
this is string 1</br>This is sample</br>this is string 2</br>*3 is duplicate of 4* this is string 3</br>this is string 4</br>*4 is duplicate of 3* this is string 3</br>asasaasd</br>
```

Comment: I just wanted to know the details of above code. In second for loop, how it checks for all duplicates? Does it checks that current value is not similar to previous one or current value is not duplicate to any record ?

Comment: You are welcome. In the second loop it actually checks if current value is not similar to previous value. But prior to this the containers collection in the for loop is sorted first by value then by id; hence making sure we are comparing the correct values.

Comment: The solution I have provided will work for duplicates of two entries (pairs). However if you want to handle multiple entry duplicates you will need to tweak the code (as for example, *3 is duplicate of 4 and 6* this is string 3, *4 is duplicate of 3 and 6* this is string 3, *6 is duplicate of 3 and 4* this is string 3)